How much energy is used for a Starship launch?
I want to understand how Earth will support the thousands of Starships Musk envisions.
I'm talking about the energy expended in all launch-related processes: propellant generation, transportation, deluge, etc. Manufacturing energy would also be appreciated, though presumably it would be minimal for a reusable vehicle.

related to this question; the comments there would be as relevant here

This question is similar, but not exactly the same: How does the power output of the 33 Raptors on SpaceX's Superheavy compare to the power distributed on America's electrical grid?

How exactly is this question a duplicate of that one?

I think the question is valid but not specific to space exploration, because we can ask the same "How will Earth support it" question for car manufacturing, appliance manufacturing,  electric power generation, etc. each of which will continue to grow. Building and launching rockets is just another industry, currently tiny in comparison to other industries, possibly in the future it will grow and eventually become perhaps a larger fraction of the impact of air transportation in comparison.  I don’t see how your question could be answered accurately other than by writing a research paper.

The version of Starship that was used for IFT4 lifts off with 1,022,222 kg of methane. Of course future larger versions have been announced which will carry even more fuel and liquid oxygen.
One kilogram of methane releases 50.625MJ of energy if burned with oxygen (ref). Therefore the total chemical energy in Starship when it's on the pad amounts to
$$50.625 MJ/kg \times 1,022,222 kg = 51,749,989 MJ ~= 51.75 TJ$$
If I interpret your question correctly, Elon Musk envisions sending 1000's of Starship's to Mars each Mars transfer window. It will require 1,200,000 kg of propellant to refill a Starship in orbit.
The current Starship, according to Elon, can support a payload of 40-50 tons. When given a range, its generally wise to use the value at the conservative end of the range. So, since we're fact-checking a claim here, let's apply the assumption that the 40 ton value will be achieved in practice.
In that case, it would take 1,200/40=30 refilling launches to refill Starship. We will need some additional launches to account for boil-off. Let's assume two extra launches for boil-off, and two extra launches to stock the interplanetary spacecraft with provisions for the trip. We also need to launch the interplanetary spacecraft and a "propellant depo" spacecraft. So, we're probably talking about 30+2+2+1+1 = 36 launches to LEO plus the 266,667 kg of fuel in the interplanetary Starship.
$$36 \times 1,022,222 kg + 266,667=37,066,659 kg$$
This amounts to
$$50.625 MJ/kg \times 37,066,659 kg = 1,876,499,612 MJ$$
If we want to send 2000 Starships to Mars, then we will need 3,752,999,223,750 GJ worth of Methane, or 3,752,999 TJ$$

The world uses 145,989,141 TJ of Natural gas every year, so this would require, roughly, ${1\over{39}}^{th}$ the world's yearly production of methane.
The question asked about all launch-related processes, and it is true that additional energy will be needed to run the compressors that liquify the oxygen, and lots of energy will be used to manufacture the Starships, Superheavy boosters, launch pads, ground systems, etc. There is already a similar question (and answer) that touches on this topic, so I'll refer you over there if you'd like a more fine-grained accounting of some of the other ways that rockets consume energy indirectly.
Even if we had those details, there would still be a lot of uncertainty in this estimate because we do not know yet if even 40 tons to orbit with full and rapid reusability can be achieved in practice. Also, historically the cost of fuel has represented only a tiny fraction of the total cost of a space mission. So, tallying up the energy usage only can only provide us with a very rough indication of the techno-economic feasibility of the proposed mission.
